Incorporating CGAL into an existing QT6 project
I have a QT6 project with a .pro file and I want to include the CGAL libraries I saw in a StackOverflow question where a person asked the same question but in linux and I can't find the libs folder in the windows installation folder.
The link to the question I found from stack is this: How do you include CGAL into a QT project in QT Creator?
This is my .pro file but as you can imagine, I don't have the usr/include folder so I don't know how to proceed.
# TestCGAL.pro
CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

INCLUDEPATH +=   C:/dev/CGAL-6.0/include\
LIBS        += -L/usr/include/
LIBS        += -lCGAL
LIBS        += -lgmp
LIBS        += -lmpfr // not really needed for me, but added since gmp had to be added too
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -frounding-math -O3

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target


=========================== EDIT ===========================
Since I was told that Qt6 was no longer going to work with QMAKE I decided to change my entire project to CMAKE, so far everything has gone well, I got it to work to the point where I had not incorporated CGAL, but when I tried to make an integration of the code I had CGAL, I saw problems in incorporating it into the CMAKE file.
I was guided by the link you gave me in a reply but I can't seem to recognize the CGAL installation.

The CGAL library used to use the cmake for a long time - there is a lot of examples and demos in the CGAL distribution with the CMakeLists.txt configuration files. Also, there are explanations how to use both Qt 6 and CGAL with cmake - for instance, this page.

My CMakeLists.txt file is as follows
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(cloud_analizer VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Concurrent Sql WebSockets WebChannel WebEngineWidgets CGAL OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS WebView)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Concurrent Sql WebSockets WebChannel WebEngineWidgets CGAL WebView)

include_directories("C:/Program Files/MySql/MySQL Server 8.0/include")
include_directories("C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_83_0")

link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySql/MySQL Server 8.0/lib")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_83_0/lib")


set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(cloud_analizer
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        api.h api.cpp
        funciones_standar.h funciones_standar.cpp
        cloudfunctions.h cloudfunctions.cpp
        cloudserver.h cloudserver.cpp
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET cloud_analizer APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(cloud_analizer SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(cloud_analizer
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

if(CGAL_Qt6_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(constrained PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer)
  target_link_libraries(draw_triangulation_2 PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer)
  target_link_libraries(polygon_triangulation PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer)
  target_link_libraries(star_conflict_zone PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer)
  target_link_libraries(cloud_analizer PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt6::WebView Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui Qt6::Concurrent Qt6::Sql Qt6::WebSockets Qt6::WebChannel Qt6::WebEngineWidgets mysqlclient)
else()
  message(STATUS "NOTICE: Several examples require Qt6 and will not be compiled.")
endif()
# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.cloud_analizer)
endif()
set_target_properties(cloud_analizer PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS cloud_analizer
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)


if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(cloud_analizer)
endif()

The error is specifically in the line
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Concurrent Sql WebSockets WebChannel WebEngineWidgets CGAL WebView)


C:\Users\baeza\Desktop\Analisis-de-nubes\cloud_analizer\CMakeLists.txt:13:
error: Found package configuration file:
C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake
but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
FOUND.  Reason given by package:
Failed to find required Qt component "CGAL".
Expected Config file at
"C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6CGAL/Qt6CGALConfig.cmake" does
NOT exist

This is the reference link with which I have tried to set up the CMakeLists.txt file
I also found this other link but I'm not sure how to apply it to my project.
=========================== EDIT 2 ===========================
I included in the CMakeLists.txt file the lines that were recommended to me in a commentary
set(CGAL_DIR "C:/dev/CGAL-6.0/lib/cmake/CGAL")
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Qt6 Core)

and the line
target_link_libraries(cloud_analizer PRIVATE CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer)

Now when I put #include <CGAL/*> I recognize perfectly the library, the problem is that now the line private slots: in a class file that I have in my program is not recognized, I was investigating a little and according I found the problem is because it does not recognize the QObject that belongs to core, but I am incorporating Core in the lines
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Concurrent Sql WebSockets WebChannel WebEngineWidgets WebView)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Concurrent Sql WebSockets WebChannel WebEngineWidgets WebView)

And below next to the findpackage
target_link_libraries(cloud_analizer PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt6::WebView Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui Qt6::Concurrent Qt6::Sql Qt6::WebSockets Qt6::WebChannel Qt6::WebEngineWidgets mysqlclient)

This is the file with the problem
mainwindow.h
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtWebSockets/QtWebSockets>
#include "cloudfunctions.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void actualizarProgreso();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    CloudFunctions *mCloud;

};

If I comment the CGAL lines, this error disappears and QObject recognizes me perfectly, but I need CGAL, that's the point of it all.

The Qt 6 build system doesn't use the qmake together with pro-files anymore - please see this page. From this page:

The Qt 5 build system was built on top of qmake. In Qt 6, we ported the build system to CMake.

The CGAL library used to use the cmake for a long time - there is a lot of examples and demos in the CGAL distribution with the CMakeLists.txt configuration files. Also, there are explanations how to use both Qt 6 and CGAL with cmake - for instance, this page.

I have edited the question with a second attempt but with CMAKE but I have found some errors when applying it

@DanielOcanto - the CGAL can't be a component of Qt6. I think you need to add the command find_package(CGAL REGUIRED COMPONENTS Qt6). Then the variable CGAL_Qt6 will be defined and set to true. Also an essential command is target_link_libraries(<...your project...> CGAL::CGAL CGAL::CGAL_Qt6)

I updated the question with your corrections, I found another error in some program files related to QT.

@DanielOcanto - maybe you just need to replace the CGAL target CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer by the target CGAL::CGAL_Qt6 (as I said before). The CGAL Basic Viewer is a simplified way to draw some CGAL objects, and it looks like it prohibits usage of Qt signals and slots
